# Cannot resolve method getAccount()

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-signin

So I've been following the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) to set up Google Sign-In, and this is the final bit of code required (with minor modifications):

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    System.out.println("TAG - handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        GoogleAccountCredential gac =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,
            Collections.singleton(YOUTUBE_SCOPE));
        Account account = acct.getAccount(); // <--- Cannot resolve method getAccount()
    }
}
```

It cannot resolve the [`getAccount()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getAccount()) method even though it is [documented](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getAccount()) as being an available method for `GoogleSignInAccount`.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Can you post the *full* error message that you're seeing?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The title is the full error message given by `IntelliJ`

Comment: This is driving me insane ...

Comment: I'll bet it is. I assume that you've closed your IDE, re-started things, tried to re-code it in isolation.... all the usual debugging tricks?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes and yes, its already running in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out:

In the app level `build.gradle` file I changed

```
...

dependencies{
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    ...
}

...
```

to

```
...

dependencies{
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
    ...
}

...
```

Version `9.0.0` does not include the `getAccount()` method.